# Regex Help matching quotes

Tags: regex

I havin a reg ex problemm i would like to have a reg ex that will match the '\nGO  at the end of my file(see below.) I have got the following so far:

```
^\'*GO
```

but its match the quote sysbol?

EOF:

```
WHERE     (dbo.Property.Archived <> 1)
'
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl \Z matches the end of the string, totally ignoring line breaks. Use this to match GO on the last line of a file if the file is loaded into a string:

```
^GO\Z
```

POSIX regex uses \' instead of \Z.

To match exactly the newline and then the word GO in your example, you want this:

```
\nGO
```

You can also do this:

```
\n.*GO
```

This last regular expression will match what you want in your example, but the .* part will make it so there can be anything (or nothing) in between the newline and GO.